# How can I implement a pre-processing app for bank statement CSV files?

Tags: windows, perl, scripting, windows-7, command-line

I wish to write some sort of pre-processor for bank statement data provided in the form of a CSV file. Requirements are quite simple, and include:

1. Only extracting one particular set of rows from the input file.
2. Transforming a custom date format to a standard, recognized date format.
3. Interpreting the [DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits)/[CR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits) indicator and appropriately setting the sign on the amount field.
4. <strike>Parsing a memo type field into separate fields, based on data at the beginning of the memo field.</strike>

I could eat this for breakfast in a simple C# command line tool, but I think this application is much more suited to a scripted, non-compiled implementation. I want to avoid VBScript at all costs, just because it's so ugly. I have just installed ActivePerl and would like to get to know Perl much better, but I have no idea where to even start.

I think my most effective question here would then be: Where can I find articles or examples etc. that will help be achieve what I want to, preferably using a scripting platform readily available for Windows 7.

**ADDED:**  Based on initial feedback, it looks like I will be using Perl with the [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) and [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time%3a%3aPiece) packages. I can easily install these with **ppm**, but how would I deploy my solution to a target Windows 7 client machine? I would much prefer to avoid having to include instructions for the client to *type 'ppm xxxx' and wait for the package to install* etc.

Comment: For csv data, you can check out the [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) and [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to perl! To get you started, you should always begin your script with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This will save you lots of troubles later because it forces you to declare your variables and gives you warnings.

For your particular task, perl has lots of modules that can do a lot of the work for you. <strike>You can install these using `ppm` (Perl Package Manager, which comes with ActiveState). Just run it from the command line and it will open up a GUI.</strike>

The modules that I suggest for you to use are:

1. [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) which will do the CSV parsing for you. You can then access each row as an array reference.
2. [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Piece/Piece.pm) which can parse the date (using strptime()) into a date/time object.

The documentation for every module includes a `SYNOPSIS` at the beginning, which is usually sample code that is very helpful to get you started on using it.

For the other tasks, you should be able to use core perl. You may need to use regular expressions (see [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html)) to parse the memo type. Or you could possibly use the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function, depending on what you need to do.

Beyond that, you'll just have to learn perl. The [online tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) should be of help.

### UPDATE

To deploy your app, you could:

- Run the script as is, assuming your users have ActiveState Perl installed on their own PCs. I've struck out my bit on PPM because the modules that I've specified (and a whole lot of other commonly used ones) are actually included with ActiveState Perl 5.10 or later, so no one needs to install anything else.
- *[Less preferred since you're trying to avoid compiling]* Compile the script into an exe. This will ensure that any required modules are included. The catch is that activestate's compiler `perlapp` (which comes with [Perl Dev Kit](http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit)) requires a commercial licence. Alternatively, [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) includes tools which will help you compile on Windows.

Comment: When you are talking about Perl the language, capitalize the first letter.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any modules, consider using ADO/Text driver via Win32::OLE. The `C:\Perl\eg\aspSamples` folder contains some samples, just ignore the ASP parts. Driver specific info are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx).